# IntelliJ Idea broke editing after random period of time

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I have a problem with IntelliJ Idea IDE, I'm developing Java and JSF code. After I start the Intellij Idea everything is fine untill I'm not able to execute some commands (eg. Cmd + V) or enter some text (some keys just don't work inside Intellij Idea). 
When I restart the IDE everything is back to normal but only for about a 30 minutes or so (sometimes shorter).

I just bought the licence and this is really driving me crazy.

My setup is Java 1.6, OSX Lion and IntelliJ IDEA 11.

Answer (score 2):

Please [contact JetBrains support](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA) with `idea.log` attached (Help | Reveal Log in Finder).

Update: after investigating the logs, it appears to be a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81122). [Two](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79889) [other](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80181) issues are related.

Comment: Hmnn, after your suggestion I did contacted JetBrains but the reply.. hmnn is not satisfactory: 'Its a known problem and there is no workaround right now: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81122
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79889
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80181

Comment: This reply was provided by me. Sorry for the inconvenience, we'll try to resolve it in the next update.

Comment: :) Heh, cool, nice to me you on SO pages :). I'll wait for the update then